# Как поменять физический адрес в .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

Имеется путь физический от корня:

```
/upload/user/2014/14/14/pid_113456/avatar/2132434242.jpg
```

Нужно на выходе получить:

```
/img/113456/2132434242.jpg
```

при учете, что `/2014/14/14/` - папки, созданные по времени, год, месяц, день. Иными словами, их много.

Дело в том, что проект очень большой (стартап), а массу перезаливать... Адский труд. Нужды поменялись - и теперь надо сократить путь.

Comment: @pavlok2008, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь, это у вас не получится, так как часть **/2014/14/14/** нигде в урле не передаётся и получить её неоткуда.

Думаю, вам правильней написать PHP скрипт, который рекурсивно пробежал бы ваши каталоги и физически переложил ваши файлы в новые директории.

Comment: Спасибо, я так уже и сделал. Я просто думал, может, как-то из-под папок выйти на реврайт базе - сократит до корня, но опять же не перечислишь все папки и получится склейка. 

Однозначно: переписал скрипт, который все исправил, только времени заняло на полночи.